# Build static executable on RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, g++

I have a C++ project that I'm currently building using dynamic linking to various system libraries.  It's on a RHEL 7 system.  I've been using devtoolset-9 to get a more modern version of g++ (the system one is 4.8.5, I think).  It all works fine, but I'd like to now build a static executable that I will be able to run on a non-RHEL linux system.  I've tried specifying -static-libstdc++, but it appears to still be dynamically linked, looking at the ldd output.  I've read that devtoolset compilers use some link-time trickery to link in both the system libstdc++ dynamically and any new C++ functionality statically.  Is this true?  It doesn't work for me; if I copy the executable over to the non-RHEL system and try to run it, I get a bunch of things like this (from memory, so hopefully correct):

> /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Is there any way to build a fully static executable using g++ from devtoolset-9?  Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't sure which is the best forum for this question.  Advice appreciated.

Comment: -static-libstdc++ coused libstdc++ to be linked statically, it doesn't produce a static executable. If you have other C++ shared libraries, then they will bring in shared libstdc++ independently from the executable, so you have to link to static versions of those libraries or rebuild them without linking to libstdc++.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense.  Thanks.